# jquery simulate enter key on google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Using `google maps api` and trying to search location by `select option value`, actually i move select option text to google maps search box and it works good but google maps search box need `enter` to action and now i want to simulate `enter key` on this search box, everything looks good but this simulation not working on this search box, any solution?

```
 $('#test').change(function() {
          var val = $('#test option:selected').text();
          $('#pac-input').val(val);
          var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
          e.which = 13;
          $("#pac-input").trigger(e);
        });

        $("#pac-input").keydown(function(e) {
          if (e.which = 13) {
            alert('Enter Pressed');
          }
        });
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5mLg0fe7/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found the solution, actually first need to `focus` then `keydown` function and also should use `google.maps.event.trigger`:

```
 $('#test').change(function() {
  var val = $('#test option:selected').text();
  $('#pac-input').val(val);

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'focus')
  google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', {
    keyCode: 13
  })
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5mLg0fe7/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

**if (e.which = 13) {** is the line causing this issue.
Replace this with **if (e.which == 13) {** and this should solve your problem. In the first case since you are assigning the value its always returning true for all cases. **==** will check it for truthness and not simple assign it.

Comment: Okay. I'm sorry I that didn't strike me. However, with a few tweaks from your new solution, your old solution also works. This is the link https://jsfiddle.net/3t95nofm/

Comment: i see still not working,  after change select option, maps should change to that city you have selected.

Comment: You're right. First trigger focus and then Trigger keydown. Thanks :) Updated Link-https://jsfiddle.net/393qh927/